# How to color only part which is needed in QGraphicsEllipseItem

Tags: pyqt

I am trying to color a circle(QGraphicsEllipseItem) 25% blue, 25% transparent, 25% red, 25% transparent inside QGraphicsScene. I am struggling to do so. I tried to do something like this:

```
class CircleItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, radius=0):
        super(CircleItem, self).__init__(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2))

        gradient = QRadialGradient(self.boundingRect().center(), radius)
        gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.blue)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.25, Qt.transparent)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.5, Qt.red)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.75, Qt.transparent)
        self.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
```

but it doesn't really fill anything, is there anyway to paint circle the way i want it? Like on picture

[image]

Comment: That's not what QRadialGradient does. Use QConicalGradient, and repeat the color close to the next range (eg. `gradient.setColorAt(0.2499, Qt.blue)`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong gradient type.

QRadialGradient spreads the gradient with different *radius* values, as also shown in the [QGradient documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgradient.html#details):

[image: Image of a Qt radial gradient]

What you need is a [QConicalGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qconicalgradient.html):

[image: Image of a Qt conical gradient]

Then, even using the proper gradient type, it will not show "sections" of the circle as you want with the given values: you are using a *gradient*, so its colors gradually change between its *stops*.

After changing the gradient type (and using the default 0 [`angle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qconicalgradient.html#angle) value) as with the following:

```py
        gradient = QConicalGradient(self.boundingRect().center(), 0)
        gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.blue)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.25, Qt.transparent)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.5, Qt.red)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.75, Qt.transparent)
```

The result will still not be appropriate, and that's because a gradient uses color interpolation, which is the main purpose of a *gradient*:

[image: invalid gradient]

A possible solution is to use narrow values next to color changes, for instance:

```py
        gradient = QConicalGradient(self.boundingRect().center(), 0)
        gradient.setColorAt(0, Qt.blue)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.2499, Qt.blue)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.25, Qt.transparent)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.4999, Qt.transparent)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.5, Qt.red)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.7499, Qt.red)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.75, Qt.transparent)
```

This is much better, as there is almost no interpolation:

[image: better gradient]

Still, not enough. Even with the small difference between stops, there can be issues at higher resolutions:

[image: not so better]

Notice the small artifact on top. This is even more visible if the gradient has a different angle with the following change:

```py
        gradient = QConicalGradient(self.boundingRect().center(), 15)
```

<sup>Note the `15` value, which rotates the gradient 15° counter-clockwise.</sup>

Even when using antialiasing, the gradient is still aliased:

[image: really, not better at all]

Note that setting the rotation of the item will *not* solve the issue.

A much better visual result can only be obtained by custom painting, which involves a QGraphicsEllipseItem subclass that internally sets "slices" and overrides painting on its own.

This approach may seem a bit complex, but it's also required for proper displaying, and allows further extensibility (like multiple colors or different extents for each color).

```py
class SmoothCircleItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    _colors = None
    _colorAngle = 0
    _colorRanges = None
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, radius=1, colors=None, angle=0):
        super().__init__(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2))
        if colors is None:
            colors = (Qt.blue, Qt.transparent, Qt.red, Qt.transparent)
        self.setColors(colors, angle)

    def setColors(self, colors, angle=None):
        # acceptable values for "colors" are lists or tuples of:
        # - QColor, Qt.GlobalColor (or their int values)
        # - list/tuples of [color, position]
        if isinstance(colors[0], (QColor, Qt.GlobalColor, int)):
            # accept an arbitrary list of colors that splits the ellipse 
            # assigning identical parts to each color
            _colors = []
            ratio = 1 / len(colors)
            pos = 0
            for c in colors:
                if not isinstance(c, QColor):
                    c = QColor(c)
                _colors.append((c, pos))
                pos += ratio
            colors = _colors

        else:
            # accept iterables in the form of [color, pos], with positions
            # in real ranges between 0.0 and 1.0
            colors = sorted(
                [(c, p % 1.) for c, p in colors], 
                key=lambda cd: cd[1]
            )

        # create an internal list of colors in the following form:
        # [color, start, extent]
        first = colors[0]
        last = [first[0], first[1] % 1.]
        self._colors = [last]
        for color, pos in colors[1:]:
            last.append((pos - last[-1]))
            colorData = [color, pos]
            self._colors.append(colorData)
            last = colorData
        if len(colors) > 1:
            last.append(1. + first[1] - last[-1])
        else:
            last.append(1.)

        if self._colorAngle == angle:
            self._update()
        elif isinstance(angle, (int, float)):
            self.setColorAngle(angle)

    def setColorAngle(self, angle):
        angle = angle % 360
        if self._colorAngle != angle:
            self._colorAngle = angle
            self._update()

    def _update(self):
        if self._colorAngle:
            # adjust the start values based on the angle
            realAngle = self._colorAngle / 360
            values = [(c, (s + realAngle) % 1, e) for c, s, e in self._colors]
        else:
            values = self._colors

        # update angles using QPainter angles, which are in sixteenths
        self._colorRanges = [
            (c, int(s * 5760), int(e * 5760)) for c, s, e in values
        ]
        self.update()

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget=None):
        rect = self.rect()
        qp.save()
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        for color, start, extent in self._colorRanges:
            qp.setBrush(color)
            qp.drawPie(rect, start, extent)
        qp.restore()
        super().paint(qp, opt, widget)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        grad = brush.gradient()
        if grad is None or grad.type() != grad.ConicalGradient:
            return
        self.setColors([(stop[1], stop[0]) for stop in grad.stops()])
```

The visual difference is quite clear, from the following comparison (the first is the QGradient based item, the second is the above `SmoothCircleItem` with similar values, while the third shows a possible extension with different color data:

[image: wonderful output!]